# How can we draw the contour line?

Tags: calculus, functions, multivariable-calculus, curves

Let $f:\mathbb{R}_+^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $y=f(x_1,x_2)=\sqrt{x_1 \cdot x_2}$.

I want to draw the contour line $y=2$.

$$$$

We have that $\sqrt{x_1\cdot x_2}=2\Rightarrow x_1\cdot x_2=4$.

How can we draw the contour line? What kind of curve is this?

$$$$

**EDIT**:

For $x_1=1$ we get $x_2=4$, for $x_1=2$ we get $x_2=2$, for $x_1=4$ we get $x_2=1$ so do we get :

[image]

?

Comment: To draw the contour-line just choose several $x_1$-values and calculate the corresponding $x_2$-values. You get points lying on the contour line

Comment: For $x_1=1$ we get $x_2=4$, for $x_1=2$ we get $x_2=2$, for $x_1=4$ we get $x_2=1$ so do we get : https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaLxB.png ? @Peter

Comment: Or is the a straight line between the points $(1,4), (2,2), (4,1)$, etc? @Peter

Comment: But we have that $f:\mathbb{R}_+^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, doesn't mean that $x_1, x_2\geq 0$ ? @Peter

Comment: Yes, of course, I did not look at the domain. So it is only the "right half" of the hyperbola.

Comment: So, is what I drawed correct? @Peter

Comment: Ok, I will do that... @Peter

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, this is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x_1x_2=4$ and $x_i \neq 0$, then
$$x_2 = \frac{4}{x_1}$$
This a [hyperbola from high school](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20y%3D4%2Fx), think $y=\frac{1}{x}$ in good old-fashioned $xy$-coordinates.

Comment: For $x_1=1$ we get $x_2=4$, for $x_1=2$ we get $x_2=2$, for $x_1=4$ we get $x_2=1$ so do we get : https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaLxB.png ?

Comment: Or is the a straight line between the points $(1,4), (2,2), (4,1)$, etc?

Comment: @MaryStar It's a smooth curve like the one I gave in the link.

Comment: Ah ok!! Thank you!! :-)